# How to find the last occurrence of an element in a Scala List?

Tags: scala

I have a List of **Student**s from which I want to find the *last matching* student whose age is 23.

I know that `find()` method gives us the *first matching occurrence* as shown below:

```
case class Student(id: Int, age: Int)

val students = List(Student(1, 23), Student(2, 24), Student(3, 23))

val firstStudentWithAge23 = students.find(student => student.age == 23)
// Some(Student(1, 23))
```

This code gives me the first matching student. But I need the last matching student.

For now, I am using `reverse` method followed by `find`:

```
val lastStudentWithAge23 = students.reverse.find(student => student.age == 23)
// Some(Student(3,23))
```

This gives me the last matching student.

But this doesn't not seem to be a good approach since the whole list has to be reversed first. How can I achieve this in a better yet functional way ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`chengpohi`'s and `jwvh`'s answers work, but will traverse the list twice or more.

Here's a generic way to find the last occurence that will only traverse the list once:

```
def findLast[A](la: List[A])(f: A => Boolean): Option[A] =
  la.foldLeft(Option.empty[A]) { (acc, cur) => 
    if (f(cur)) Some(cur)
    else acc
  }
```

We walk through the collection exactly once and always take the last element that matches our predicate `f`.

Answer (score 11):

[As of Scala 2.13](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/7551), you can use [`findLast`](https://ashawley.github.io/scala/2.13.0-RC1/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#findLast(p:A=%3EBoolean):Option[A]) to find the last element of a `Seq` satisfying a predicate, if one exists:

```scala
val students = List(Student(1, 23), Student(2, 24), Student(3, 23))
students.findLast(_.age == 23) // Option[Student] = Some(Student(3, 23))
```

Answer (score 5):

I think maybe you can achieve this by `filter` with `lastOption`, like:

```
list.filter(student => student.age == 23).lastOption
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list.lift(list.lastIndexWhere(_.age == 23))
```

Indexing on a `List` isn't optimum, but it's an option.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another approach, using `partition`, for instance as follows,

```
val (l, _) = list.partition(_.age == 23)
l.lastOption
```

which delivers the list bisected into a tuple of those aged 23 in order of occurrence in the original list, and the rest. From the first tuple take the last item.